# What is the relationship between microservices and cloud-native architecture?

Tags: cloud, microservices

I often see microservices and cloud-native architectures in articles. The two are very similar, but it is not clear what kind of relationship they are?

Answer (score 0):

Both concepts are related. The cloud native concept is related to how you build your software. Here is the definition from Pivotal:

"Cloud Native describes the patterns of high performing organizations delivering software faster, consistently and reliably at scale". – Pivotal

Therefore one "tool" that helps you deliver software faster is microservices, which in turn is related to docker, Kubernetes.

I can deploy my application using Kubernetes and follow the microservices patterns, but it will not necessarily be a cloud native application.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's like all about achieving something at low costs.

The major cloud providers are looking to provide the required infra at lower cost than the respective organization shall pay to have on it's own and manage it.

So almost every new development is happening using cloud native services.

And necessarily it has nothing to do with Microservices, you can host like any application at cloud. Microservices is just an another development approach like SOA, Monolith.